# Rule for derivation: $d^n/dt^n$, where $t = -ln(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

> I'm trying to show that 
>   $$ (-1)^{n+1} \frac{d^n}{dt^n}(1 - e^{-t})^\alpha = -(x \frac{d}{dx})^n(1-x)^\alpha$$
>
> where $x = e^{-t}$, $\alpha > 1, n > 0$.

If I understand correctly, $$ \frac{d}{dt} = \frac{d}{d(-\ln(x))} = -x\frac{d}{dx}$$

However, it's not clear how does the second (and further) derivatives follow:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}(-x \frac{d}{dx}) = -x\frac{d}{dx}(-x \frac{d}{dx}) \stackrel{?}{=}(-1)^2 x^2 \frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}$$

Do $\frac{d}{dx}$ just multiplies like that? If so, why does this hold? That is, why isn't $\frac{d}{dx}(-x \frac{d}{dx}) = -1 \frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx} -x \underbrace{\frac{d(\frac{d}{dx})}{dx}}_{=0? ~~ =d^2/dx^2?}$ as would be following the chain rule with ordinary variables (instead of $d/dx$)?

In other words, I don't understand how exactly manipulating $d/dx$ works.

Comment: Try induction. ${}$

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your notation. $\frac{d}{dt}$ is an operator, so $\frac{d}{dx}$ doesn't really mean anything by itself. Something like $\frac{d(\ln t)}{dt}$, however does, and it evaluates to $-\frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: @Infiaria Probably because I am confused too. [In various literature](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0909/0909.0979.pdf) I find both ways of using the operator, both $x \frac{d}{dx}$ at, i.e., (2.2) and the usual$\frac{d}{dt} f$ in other (i.e., (3.8)).

Comment: @Nutle Something like $\left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right)^n f(x)$ is just shorthand for $x^n \frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n}$, which is fine. I'm just not sure about your usage though.

Comment: @Infiaria okay, that makes sense, thanks. Still, even with $f(t)$, I can't see why doesn't the following hold: $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}f(t)) = -x \frac{d}{dx}(-x \frac{d}{dx}f(x)) = -x \cdot (-1 \frac{d}{dx}f(x) - x \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x))$

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is correct and basically all you need. Remember that these exponents mean "applying after another":
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}t^n} f(t)= \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\cdots \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f(t)\right)}_{\text{$n$-times}}.$$
Since you already arrived at the expression
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} = -x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$$ you can solve the problem now by just substituting:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}t^n} f(t)= \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\cdots \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}f(t)\right)}_{\text{$n$-times}}=\left(-x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^n f(t).$$
In your case:
$$(-1)^{n+1} \frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}t^n} (1-e^{-t})^\alpha = (-1)^{n+1}\left(-x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^n (1-x)^\alpha = -\left(x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^n(1-x)^\alpha.$$

Comment: Thanks! Could you clarify though, how would the substitution work on, say, the second derivative? I'm still confused and don't see why doesn't the following hold: $\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{d}{dt}f(t)) = -x \frac{d}{dx}(-x \frac{d}{dx}f(x)) = -x \cdot (\underbrace{-1 \frac{d}{dx}f(x)} - x \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x))$. Do I make the substitution from $t$ to $x$ too soon?